# Bitcoin node GUI shutting down right away

Tags: bitcoin-core

My node was running fine until I decided to change the setting under the nerwork tab, I checked the box for "Use separate SOCKS5 proxy to reach peers via Tor onion services" and on Proxy IP box I put 127.0.0.1:9150, on Port box 9150. When I tried to restart the node it wont start anymore, it gives me "Error 127.0.0.1:9150 incorrect Proxy" and it shuts down immediately. What can I do to get the node to start again?  the GUI is not even starting. I just stared exploring with bitcoin nodes and Im not knowledgable at all, any help will be greatly appreciated. Im running the node on Debian Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I would

Navigate to the Bitcoin data directory. Usually `%APPDATA%\Bitcoin\` on Windows.

1. Have a look at the end of the log file (`debug.log`)
2. Rename the configuration file (`bitcoin.conf`), if it then starts OK, reconfigure.

---

Related questions:

- [What to look for in Bitcoin-core logfile when something bad happens](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/105973/13866)

Other useful references

- https://achow101.com/2016/07/Bitcoin-Core-Troubleshooting